# The 'termux-battery-status' command in (Termux: API) does not work

Tags: android-9.0-pie, termux

I want to know the current battery value on my phone, but I can not do this. When I enter the 'termux-battery-status' command, my terminal hangs (it doesn’t output anything).

I read on various forums about changing application settings [Like this](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/334#issuecomment-340581650) or [like this](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/334).

My telephone:

```
$ termux-info
Packages CPU architecture: aarch64
Updatable packages: All packages up to date
Android version: 9
Kernel build information: Linux localhost 4.9.117+ #4 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 8 17:13:44 CST 2019 aarch64 Android
Device manufacturer: Blackview
Device model: A60Pro
```

Termux Settings:

[image: TermuxSetting]

I do not understand how to fix this. :/
Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the Termux:API app on your device : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.api

After installation, head over to App Info for the Termux:API app, and allow all the permissions including Modifying System Setting.

[image: Application Info]

Answer (score 0):

Try `termux-api-start` command first. This is what helped me

Answer (score 0):

## RUN Termux-API in your phone in 2023

#### This will solve all the termux-api problems including Termux-battery-status issue.

*Since Developers have stopped updating the playstore version of termux it is not going to work properly, so from now on we have to use termux from the f-droid website. Also, you need to install the termux-api.apk to make these api commands work. below is the simple code that can make everything work in few seconds*

1. So firstly install termux application from F-Droid, [Download link](https://f-droid.org/repo/com.termux_118.apk). If you are already using the F-Droid version, then skip this step.
2. Just copy the entire code directly and paste it inside your termux. it will open the termux-api page for you, just install it and everything will be fixed.

   > echo -e "\e[031m" "HEY, MAKE SURE TO INSTALL THE TERMUX API APP THEN
   > COME BACK AGAIN IN TERMUX" && sleep 2 && xdg-open
   > "https://f-droid.org/repo/com.termux.api_51.apk"&& echo -e '\e[032m'
   > 'HAVE YOU INSATLLED TERMUX API APK? IF YESS THEN PRESS ENTER, IF NO
   > THEN RE-RUN THE SCRIP AND THIS TIME INSTALL THE APK IN YOU PHONE'  &&
   > read r && pkg install "termux-api" && exit
3. type termux-battery-status to find the battery info.

4. To make everything work even smoother, go in your settings>apps> search Termux:API and make sure to allow every permission you can enable.

Comment: “This will solve all the termux-api problems” seems a little overstated — it didn't work for me, at least… 

Comment: Have you tried all the steps? What is the issue are you facing? I think if anyone will follow the below steps, there is no chance of this not Woking.

Comment: The Termux API works for a while after a reboot, but then stops working again. [This issue](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/issues/447) describes it; at the bottom is [this commit](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/commit/f2c1342f6f89aaf527df16c923dda0d4cae73faa) which seems to explain the problem and provide a fix. (Though it hasn't been released yet, so it's not available without deleting all of Termux and reinstalling the nightly version from scratch…)

Answer (score -1):

download termux api app from play store then you can easily use that commands its 200% true just try its only 2MB app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Same solution as the other answer.